# Diretório como se fosse pasta raiz PHP

Tags: php

Olá, por questão de organização eu queria fazer uma coisa, todos os arquivos ficam na pasta raiz por exemplo:

**htdocs\index.php** por organização eu queria aprender a fazer assim: **htdocs\template\index.php**

**e todos que solicitarem outros url irá ler todos arquivos da pasta templates**
por exemplo:
**htdocs\template\pagina2.php** 
**htdocs\template\pagina3.php** 
e assim vai.

Então ficaria assim:

meusite.com/pagina2

porém não sei como, com include não deu muito certo

meu index.php:

```
<?php include ''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/template/'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'.php';
```

meu index.php da pasta template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Bem vindo ao site</title</head<body>Teste</body></html>
```

Tentei do modo acima mas não deu certo

Comment: Você verificou o valor de `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` antes de tentar o include? Só concatenar deixará o caminho certo do arquivo?

Comment: Você pode alterar seu servidor web para utilizar o template como diretório raiz também.

Comment: Anderson eu tentei de alguns jeitos e todos deram errados até com if, gmsantos, eu estou montando uma cms pública então são diferentes servidores que irão usar